# ant design Как определить что Select в данный момент раскрыт?

Tags: reactjs, ant-design

Подскажите как определить что в данный момент Select раскрыт ?
(находится в состоянии выбора из возможных опций)
В документации https://ant.design/components/select/#API описано свойство `open`
но как к нему обратиться через `inputSearchType.current` ?
(и похоже оно только для установки начального состояния Select)

```
  <Select ref={inputSearchType} id='sType'
    defaultValue={searchType}
    style={{ marginLeft: 10, width: 150 }} size='small'
    onChange={value => {
      inputSearchType.current.state = value
    }}            
  >
    <Option value="газ">газ</Option>
    <Option value="нефть">нефть</Option>
    <Option value="уголь">уголь</Option>
    <Option value="все">- все ресурсы -</Option>
  </Select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Там есть колбэк onDropdownVisibleChange Call when dropdown open function(open)